# Element: type is invalid Error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to call a component from another component. However, I get these two error:

> 1 of 2 errors on the page
>   React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in. Check your code at displayRevenue.js
>
> 2 of 2 errors on the page
>   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
>   Check the render method of `DisplayRevenue`

`Parent Component` ie `DisplayRevenue` is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import ListData from './listdata.js'
var axios = require('axios');

class DisplayRevenue extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[] }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
   this.loadRevenue(this.props.url, this.props.token);
 }

  setData(data){
    this.setState(data:data);
    console.log(this.state.data);    //this gives output as json object
  }

  loadRevenue(url,token){
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
     .then( (response) => {
    //   console.log(response.data);
       this.setData(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Revenue "+error);
     });
  }

  render() {
  var ListData = this.state.data.map( (invoice) => {return <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>})
    return (
      <ListData />
    );
  }
};

export default DisplayRevenue;
```

`Child Component` ie `ListData` is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class ListData extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {"HI"}
      </div>
    );
  }
  //{this.props.data.map( (invoice) => <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>)}
}

export default ListData;
```

- Both of these components are in same folder ie 'components'
- What is causing this error?

**NOTE:** I know questions with this issue has been asked before but none of them solve my error.

Comment: The error says it all: The problem is that you are overwriting `ListData` with an array: `var ListData = this.state.data.map(...)`. This overwrites the component you are importing. You cannot use an array (object) as a "React component" in `<ListData />`. As the error says, `ListData` must be a function or a string. It's not clear what you intend to do with the data you are mapping.

Comment: @FelixKling even OP is  overwriting ListData, this `{ListData}` should work.

Comment: @Ved: Context is important. `{ListData}` alone creates an object with property `ListData`. `render` must return a React element, not an arbitrary object. `return <div>{ListData}</div>;` would work, but then what is the purpose of the `ListData` component?

Comment: Thank you. I got my mistake. Btw, is there any way I can write this component within same file (Parent Component) ie. `DisplayRevenue `

Comment: Of course... just put the class definition in the same file. As the error says, a class/function or a string is expected. React doesn't care *where* that class/function comes from.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you

Comment: Seems like at least something here should be an answer to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Felix Kling said there's problem in **overwriting the component** in the code. Try this instead:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
//import ListData from './listdata.js'
var axios = require('axios');

class DisplayRevenue extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[] }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
   this.loadRevenue(this.props.url, this.props.token);
 }

  setData(data){
    this.setState(data:data);
    console.log(this.state.data);    //this gives output as json object
  }

  loadRevenue(url,token){
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
     .then( (response) => {
    //   console.log(response.data);
       this.setData(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Revenue "+error);
     });
  }

  render() {
  //var ListData = this.state.data.map( (invoice) => {return <div>{invoice.customerNumber}</div>})
    return (
      <ListData data={this.state.data}/>
    );
  }
};

export default DisplayRevenue;

class ListData extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.data.map( (invoice) => <div>{invoice.customerNumber} </div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```