# How to resolve 'Invalid Element Type' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have this modified version of react-bootstrap navbar component from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/ saved in a file named **navigation.js**. I've exported and imported it into my main **App.js** file. Yet, I still get this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Navigation`.

The weirdest part is that the error page points at the **index.js** file indicating that the error is in this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

**[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSgVV.jpg) is a screenshot of the error page.**

I know that *'Element type is invalid'* error happens either if you didn't export the component correctly (which I did) or you mixed the component and import names.

Here is the code for the **navigation.js** component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {NavDropdown, Navbar, NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

class Navigation extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Header>
                        <Navbar.Brand>
                            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                    </Navbar.Header>

                    <Nav>
                        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
                        <NavDropdown eventKey={3} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={3.1}>Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={3.2}>Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={3.3}>Something else here</NavDropdown.Item>
                            <NavDropdown.Item divider />
                            <NavDropdown.Item eventKey={3.3}>Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                        </NavDropdown>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
            
        );
    }
}

// As you can see the component is exported perfectly
export default Navigation;
```

And here is the **App.js** file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Intro from './components/intro';
import Explore from './components/explore';
import Navigation from './components/navigation';
import './App.css';


class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className = 'App-header'>
          <Navigation/>
          <Intro/>
          <Explore/>
      </div>
       
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Before you criticize, I did my research before asking this question and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189217/element-type-is-invalid-error) as the most relevant question available on StackOverflow but the concepts are different and it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It might seem like a silly thing to point out but just offhand I don't see any other issues: are you sure your `Nav` component is in a file called `Navbar`? Also have you tried importing using `./components/Navbar.jsx`?

Comment: Can you add the imports in the NavBar.js file?

Comment: Check the answer I added. It should solve your issue.

Comment: There's an ambiguity in your Navbar file with `Nav` and also, it's missing the imports for the other types, like `Component`, `Navbar`, etc.

Comment: You updated the Navigation component snippet, but there's still a `<Nav>` component that's not imported anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the `Nav` as the name of the component and exporting. 
But you are also importing some other `Nav` from a different source.

Your problem is because of the naming. Just change the name of your component and export, it should work.

EDIT:

`Navbar.Header` has been removed. And I can't even find `NavItem` in their documentation right now. There is only `Nav.Item`

Comment: I changed the name of the file to **navigation.js** and exported the component as `Navigation` but the error remains still. I also edited the code of the question, you should check it out.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of react-bootstrap?

Comment: Can you send the link to the documentation you're reading? Mine might be outdated.